# Not able to get the Videos in the RecylerView from the server

Tags: java, android

`Actually I want to display the list of videos from the server in the RecylerView I created, it contains the TextView(like whether it is Facebook, youtube video) and a VideoView(to display the video) 
for this, I write some code inside the bindobject() method in VideoAdapter class.

After writing the code I got the TextView field but not the video, any help would be appreciated???

Here is the code:`

````
package com.fitness.client.ui.main.fragments.gallery.adapter;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.MediaController;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.fitness.client.R;
import com.fitness.client.api.user.GalleryResponse;
import com.fitness.client.base.classes.BaseRecyclerViewAdapter;
import com.fitness.client.base.classes.BaseViewHolder;
import com.fitness.client.databinding.ItemProfileVideoBinding;

import java.util.List;

public class VideoAdapter extends BaseRecyclerViewAdapter<VideoAdapter.VideoHolder, GalleryResponse.Video_galleryEntity> {


    public VideoAdapter(List<GalleryResponse.Video_galleryEntity> data) {
        super(data);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public VideoHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new VideoHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_profile_video, parent, false));
    }

    class VideoHolder extends BaseViewHolder<GalleryResponse.Video_galleryEntity, ItemProfileVideoBinding> {

        public VideoHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        protected void bindObject(GalleryResponse.Video_galleryEntity object) {
            getViewDataBinding().videoText.setText(object.getVideo_type());

           //Getting video
            String video_url = object.getVideo();
            Log.e("MyFragment", "Video-url: " + video_url );

            Uri uri = Uri.parse(video_url);
            getViewDataBinding().video.setVideoURI(uri);
            getViewDataBinding().video.start();
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: My first recommendation is to create a custom view class that contains the video player and the textview you want to display and give it methods for setting that data publicly. Then instantiate that custom view class inside your viewholder. I've never had good luck with Inflating layouts directly and it working the way I wanted. I'm not sure if this would solve your question, but it might.

Answer (score 0):

If you use VideoView it will be not efficient Because the video needs to be streamed I recommend you to use  [EXO player](https://exoplayer.dev/) It is created by google it handles all the steaming part and also you can read the documentation there

Comment: Thanks for your comment I rectified it successfully